# Unity sqlite c# object reference not set to an instance of an object and database locked

Tags: c#, sqlite, unity-game-engine

i really don't know what's the problem here, it always says database locked when executing query and reference not set when i try to get data from input field. 
please help..

```
public InputField username;
public InputField password;
public Button register;
SqliteConnection dbconn;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    username = gameObject.GetComponent<InputField> ();
    password = gameObject.GetComponent<InputField> ();
    register = gameObject.GetComponent<Button> ();
    string conn = "URI=file:" + Application.dataPath + "/thesisdatabase.db";
    dbconn = new SqliteConnection (conn);
    dbconn.Open ();

    SqliteCommand cmd = new SqliteCommand ();


    InputField.SubmitEvent usernameValue = new InputField.SubmitEvent ();
    InputField.SubmitEvent passwordValue = new InputField.SubmitEvent ();
    username.onEndEdit = usernameValue;
    password.onEndEdit = passwordValue;
    Debug.Log (usernameValue);
    //      string usernameValue = "we";
    //      string passwordValue = "wwwe";
    string sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO user (username, password) VALUES ('" +usernameValue+ "' , '"+passwordValue+"')";
    cmd.CommandText = sqlInsert;
    cmd.Connection = dbconn;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery ();
    //          register.onClick.AddListener (registerMe);

    cmd.Dispose ();
    cmd = null;
    dbconn.Close ();
    dbconn = null;



}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have some difficulties with the UI API of Unity. However, I'm not an expert with MySQL, but you should give a try to the following code:

```
// Drag & Drop the gameobject with the InputField component
public InputField username;

// Drag & Drop the gameobject with the InputField component
public InputField password;

// Drag & Drop the gameobject with the Button component
public Button register;

SqliteConnection dbconn;

// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    OpenDatabaseConnection();
    register.onClick.AddListener (OnRegisterButtonClicked);
}
void OnDestroy ()
{
    CloseDatabaseConnection();
}

private void OnRegisterButtonClicked()
{
    // Make sure the username and password are not empty
    if( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( username.text ) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty( password.text ) )
    {
        InsertUser( username.text, password.text );
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Username or password is missing");
    }
}

private void InsertUser( string username, string password )
{
    SqliteCommand cmd = new SqliteCommand ();
    string sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO user (username, password) VALUES ('" +username+ "' , '"+password+"')";
    cmd.CommandText = sqlInsert;
    cmd.Connection = dbconn;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery ();
    cmd.Dispose ();
    cmd = null;
}

private void OpenDatabaseConnection()
{
    string conn = "URI=file:" + Application.dataPath + "/thesisdatabase.db";
    dbconn = new SqliteConnection (conn);
    dbconn.Open ();
}

private void CloseDatabaseConnection()
{
    dbconn.Close ();
    dbconn = null; 
}
```

Comment: @JielNiñoGaid : Have you been able to solve your problem? Don't hesitate if my solution is not clear enough or if you have any problem with it.

Comment: i did sir but there was another problem, this only works on unity editor but when deployed to android, i can't add data

Comment: Have you any error logged by [logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html)? Are you sure the plugin (dll) you use is compatible with Android?